# FTP file name in FileInputFormat.setInputPath

Tags: hadoop, ftp, mapreduce

I have a code that reads data from FTP server using mapreduce code . The code we use to connect to ftp server is as follows `

```
    String inputPath = args[0];
    String outputPath = args[1];

   Configuration conf1 = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf1, args).getRemainingArgs();

    Path arg = new Path(inputPath);
    FTPFileSystem ftpfs = new FTPFileSystem();
    Path arg1 =new Path(outputPath);
    ftpfs.setConf(conf1);
    String ftpUser = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8");
    String ftpPass = URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8");

    String url = String.format("ftp://%s:%s@ftpserver.com",
            ftpUser, ftpPass);
    ftpfs.initialize(new URI(url), conf1);

    JobConf conf = new JobConf(FTPIF.class);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, arg1));      
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, ftpfs.makeQualified(arg));



        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(CustomInputFormat.class);
        conf.setMapperClass(CustomMap.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(CustomReduce.class);


    JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

`

The problem is this code works perfectly fine in pseudo mode but gives a login failed on server error when run on a cluster.the error stack trace is

`ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:username (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Login failed on server - 0.0.0.0, port - 21
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Login failed on server - 0.0.0.0, port - 21
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem.connect(FTPFileSystem.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ftp.FTPFileSystem.getFileStatus(FTPFileSystem.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileStatus(FileSystem.java:2106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatusInternal(FileSystem.java:1566)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1503)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:1041)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1033)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:943)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:896)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:870)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1319)
        at FTPIF.run(FTPIF.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at FTPIF.main(FTPIF.java:169)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208`

The cluster has connectivity to ftp . The credentials used are correct. Any ideas why the code is not able to connect to ftp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many nodes on your cluster and multiple mappers are trying to open connections to your FTP server then you can exceed the limit of FTP users which FTP server supports.

Comment: I got the issue solved. It was some set up issue with the FTP server .